# Why doesn't the code from my delete button that references my sql database function at all? (i can click the button but the data doesnt delete itself)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter

This code may have a few errors, but a significant one I've noticed is the error involving the delete button in the password vault, I tried multiple different ways to change how the deletion work, one of which is that I made a new definition with Pyqt5.widgets replacing tkinter as it might have been an error with the text box itself but that changed nothing. I have to put some code that isn't relevant to the question to this fix such as (the master password creation, login screen etc.) due to the program not being able to function, when I removed it. If someone could test the code itself and tell me what its lacking, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
 import sqlite3, hashlib
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
from functools import *


#Database Code
with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()


#Create Password Manager Database
cursor.execute(""" 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vault(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
site TEXT NOT NULL,
username TEXT NOT NULL,
password TEXT NOT NULL);
""")

#Pop up prompt to pop up the different types of Password
def popUp(text):
    prompt = f"Enter {text}:"
    answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", prompt)
    return answer

#Create The Window of Password Master
window = Tk()

window.title("Password Vault")

def hashPassword(input):
    hash = hashlib.md5(input)
    hash = hash.hexdigest()

    return hash


def firstScreen():
    window.geometry("250x175")

    lbl = Label(window, text="Create Master Password")
    lbl.config(anchor=CENTER)
    lbl.pack()

    txt = Entry(window, width=20)
    txt.pack()
    txt.focus()

    lbl1 = Label(window, text="Re-Enter Password")
    lbl1.pack()

    txt1 = Entry(window, width=20)
    txt1.pack()
    txt1.focus()

    lbl2 = Label(window)
    lbl2.pack()

    def savePassword():
        if txt.get() == txt1.get():
            hashedPassword = hashPassword(txt.get().encode('utf-8'))

            with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
                insert_password = """INSERT INTO masterpassword(password)
               VALUES(?)"""
                cursor.execute(insert_password, (str(hashedPassword),))
                db.commit()

            passwordVault()
        else:
            lbl2.config(text="Passwords do not match")

    btn = Button(window, text="Save", command=savePassword)
    btn.pack(pady=10)

def loginScreen():
    window.geometry("250x100")

    lbl = Label(window, text="Enter Master Password")
    lbl.config(anchor=CENTER)
    lbl.pack()

    txt = Entry(window, width=20, show="*")
    txt.pack()
    txt.focus()

    lbl1 = Label(window)
    lbl1.pack()

    def getmasterPassword():
        checkHashedPassword = hashPassword(txt.get().encode('utf-8'))
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM masterpassword WHERE id = 1 AND password= ?", [checkHashedPassword])
        print (checkHashedPassword)
        return cursor.fetchall()


    def checkPassword():
        match = getmasterPassword()
        if match:
            passwordVault()
        else:
            txt.delete(0, 'end')
            lbl1.config(text="Wrong Password")

    btn = Button(window, text="Submit", command=checkPassword)
    btn.pack(pady=10)

def passwordVault():
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    def addEntry():
        text1 = "site"
        text2 = "username"
        text3 = "password"

        site = popUp(text1)
        username = popUp(text2)
        password = popUp(text3)

        insert_fields = """INSERT INTO vault(site,username,password)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?)"""

        cursor.execute(insert_fields, (site, username, password))
        db.commit()

        passwordVault()

    window.geometry("700x350")

    lbl = Label(window, text="Password Vault")
    lbl.grid(column=1)

    btn = Button(window, text="Add Account", command=addEntry)
    btn.grid(column=1, pady=5)


    lbl = Label(window, text="Website")
    lbl.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=80)
    lbl = Label(window, text="Username")
    lbl.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=80)
    lbl = Label(window, text="Password")
    lbl.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=80)

    def removeEntry(input):
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM vault WHERE id = ?", (input,))
        db.commit()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
    if (cursor.fetchall() != None):
        i = 0
        while True:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
            array = cursor.fetchall()

            for i in range(len(array)):
                lbl1 = Label(window, text=array[i][1], font=("Calibri", 10))
                lbl1.grid(column=0, row=i + 3)
                lbl2 = Label(window, text=array[i][2], font=("Calibri", 10))
                lbl2.grid(column=1, row=i + 3)
                lbl3 = Label(window, text=array[i][3], font=("Calibri", 10))
                lbl3.grid(column=2, row=i + 3)

                btn = Button(window, text="Delete", command= partial(removeEntry, array[i][0]))
                btn.grid(column=3, row=i + 3, pady=10)

            i = i+1
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
            if(len(cursor.fetchall()) <= i):
                break


cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM masterpassword")
if cursor.fetchall():
    loginScreen()
else:
    firstScreen()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly happens? If there is an error message, show it completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: fixed the question to be more descriptive

Comment: Do you mean that the database is not changed (checked e. g. with an Sqlite editor program) or do you mean that only the GUI isn't updated?

Comment: I'm unsure about if the database is unchanged, but the GUI definitely doesn't update itself after I delete the existing data. Could this be due to a lack of tkinter code in the "removeEntry()" function? If not, is there another fix for it?

Comment: Exactly, `removeEntry` has to update the GUI, too. You can either rebuild the whole vault GUI (simple) or try to remove the widgets of the deleted row only.

Comment: do you have any recommendations or hints on how to do the first one without impacting the actual process of password storage?

Comment: The function `passwordVault` already clears `window` from previous widgets and (re)builds the list of entries from the database. Calling it at the end of `removeEntry` is probably enough.